# undefined object from php json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I try to send json array to ajax (from PHP to jQuery)

in my PHP script:

```
$value = 'test';
echo json_encode(
    array(
        'key' => $value
    )
);
exit;
```

Javascript side:

```
function sweety_ajax(url, datas)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: datas,
        success: function(r){
            return r;
        }
    });
}
```

I get the correct value with r.key inside the function, but I would like to get my "r" object like this:

```
var response = sweety_ajax(url, datas);

alert(response.key);
```

But the problem is that response object is undefined and cannot get the value of key...

Any idea?

Comment: not sure if i understood your question... but from what i understand replace **r** parameter in your callback and you will be done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX request in asynchronous. You need to pass a callback if you want to do this.

```
function sweety_ajax(url, datas, callback)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: datas,
        success: callback
    });
}

sweety_ajax(url, datas, function(response) {
  alert(response.key);
});
```

Comment: what you mean? have example please ?